# Ignoring unknown escape sequences: "\"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I am trying to start a service based on the tutorial:

```
Description=Prometheus Time Series Collection and Processing Server  
Wants=network-online.target  
After=network-online.target  
  
[Service]  
User=prometheus  
Group=prometheus  
Type=simple  
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \  
    --config.file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \  
    --storage.tsdb.path /var/lib/prometheus/ \  
    --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \  
    --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries\  
    --web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:9091"  
  
[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But every time I get `Failed to enable unit: File prometheus.service: Invalid argument` with logs:

```
systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:10: Ignoring unknown escape sequences: "\"
systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service:11: Missing '='.
```

I've tried in both nano and vi.

Comment: When using backslashes for line continuation, there must be no trailing whitespace characters after them

Answer (score 2):

The command for start Prometheus should be:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
--storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus/ \
--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries \
--web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:9091"
```

Check `=` in `--config-file` and `--storage.tsdb.path`. And remove trailing spaces